# Why does the i+=1 line block the conversion of the tuple to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I initially have this code,

```
input_list = [3.1415, True, 42, '88', (1,2), [1,[2]]]
def describe_data(L):
    for i in L:
        print("The type of element " + str(i) + " is " + str(type(i)))
        i += 1
```

running `describe_data(input_list)` got me this results

```
>>> describe_data(input_list)
The type of element 3.1415 is <class 'float'>
The type of element True is <class 'bool'>
The type of element 42 is <class 'int'>
The type of element 88 is <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    describe_data(input_list)
  File "xxxxx.py", line 7, in describe_data
    i += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

However, after I remove the `i += 1`, I do not have any error printing the tuple. getting this result...

```
>>> describe_data(input_list)
The type of element 3.1415 is <class 'float'>
The type of element True is <class 'bool'>
The type of element 42 is <class 'int'>
The type of element 88 is <class 'str'>
The type of element (1, 2) is <class 'tuple'>
The type of element [1, [2]] is <class 'list'>
```

I understand the `i += 1` is not necessary here, as the list is a sequence, where `i` will run through the list. but I do not understand why it blocks the printing of the tuple. Thank you!

Comment: It "blocks" the printing because it throws an error and stops the program's execution.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: There is no loss of output; `stdout` is still being flushed/closed as part of program shutdown. You'd only lose output if you invoked `os._exit` or otherwise "hard killed" the interpreter (managed to segfault it or something).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh interesting, I didn't know that! I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Oh nevermind, I totally misread the situation. I thought the issue was in trying to `+=` the tuple `(1, 2)`, but the error happens before that.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not an index, it's the actual value in the sequence. `'88' + 1` is clearly nonsensical in a strongly typed language, and when it happens, an exception is raised, which bypasses the rest of the code (unless caught, which you didn't do). `i += 1` isn't just unnecessary, it's unrelated to what you're doing; you think it's adjusting the index, but it isn't, it's trying to mutate the values, and when you try to do it to a `str`, the program blows up before it gets to the `tuple`.

Comment: Ahhh! I get it now. the `1` wasn't able to add into the string, thus it throws that error, and doesn't affect the other types prior to the string. thank you!

Comment: @AlvissPhua: You got it. In case it's not clear, it doesn't die with `True` because `bool` is an `int` subclass in Python; you can perform math with it (where `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0`). So `i += 1` in that case just makes `i` have a value of `2` (it loses it's `bool`ness), which is then thrown away when the `for` progresses to the next value (rebinding `i`).

Comment: Your explanation is mostly correct, but a couple of issues here. "'`'88' + 1` is clearly nonsensical in a strongly typed language" - on that basis `True + 1` would not work either, but it does; simply it doesn't have a way to add an int to a string. Secondly, "it's trying to mutate the values" - no, it's trying to compute the result of adding one to each.

Comment: @alani: `bool` is an `int` subclass; it's not violating strong typing too much to have it work in `int` math (no more than allowing `int` and `float` to interoperate). I agree "mutate the values" is a little off (it can't change the original `list`, because the values in the `list` are all immutable, so it's really making a new value and rebinding the name `i` to said new value), but there's no succinct way to describe "computing a new value and rebinding the name" that isn't confusing to new programmers. I figure they can read the comments here for details if they need it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` is wrong. The for you are doing iterates over the list, not the indexes. Your variable `i` is first 3.1415 then True, until eventually becomes '88', which causes the error.

The others don't cause errors because they can be converted to int.

Solution: remove `i += 1`